# BxSlider: "next" on last slide leads to homepage?

Tags: javascript, bxslider

I'm using bxslider, found [here](http://bxslider.com/) and I'm wondering how I can get the last slide to lead back to the homepage. Right now I'm using bxslider out of the box:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  auto: true,
  autoControls: true
});
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `infiniteLoop` option([link to the docs](http://bxslider.com/options)).
[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/jkdx8uoe/)

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. By homepage I mean the last slide should redirect to the root of the entire website